# iPhone URL Callback with aphlanumeric and dots only

Tags: ios, oauth, callback

Is there a way for an iPhone app to receive a URL callback without using the colon?

The iOS **Custom URL Schema** requires a colon : in the URL .  Unfortunately the API I'm communicating with only accepts domain names not URL's.  Colons, forward slashes etc are not accepted.  Maybe there there are other options other than the Custom URL Schema.

I need a callback like "myapp" or com.mycompany.myapp.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty much like asking "is there a way for iOS the parse JSON without the curly braces?"  No, how would it know if it were an app URL or an HTTP URL?

Comment: I thought as much but you never know unless you ask the question